# How do I use a specific host in an h2o-wave app

Tags: python, h2o, h2o-wave

Currently trying to run an h2o-wave app on a remote server.  I'm restricted to using `0.0.0.0` as the host on the server (the specific port is not as restrictive).

I've looked at the h2o [configuration documentation](https://h2oai.github.io/wave/docs/configuration) and tried several variations of what they suggest:

```sh
H2O_WAVE_INTERNAL_ADDRESS=ws://0.0.0.0:8000
H2O_WAVE_EXTERNAL_ADDRESS=ws://0.0.0.0:8000
H2O_WAVE_APP_ADDRESS=ws://0.0.0.0:8000
```

But, the app is still running on the default localhost: `http://127.0.0.1:8000`

Answer (score 1):

Just setting `H2O_WAVE_APP_ADDRESS` is enough.

```
$ H2O_WAVE_APP_ADDRESS=http://0.0.0.0:8000 uvicorn my_app:main
```